# matrix row and column not equal check if check columns has only number one

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have to check if the element of every column equal to 1 in my matrix has row and column not equal. When I tried all solutions, it was working for row == column. I tried to do a summation of each column then check if it is equal to 6 number of rows since I want all element equal 1 in columns.

this is a screenshot of my task with input and output:
[task is here as picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h43ef.png)

**task description**

> In a train schedule, the route of trains is described by a sequence of bits (1 – if the train stops at a station, 0 – if not).
> Write a program that gives the sequence of bits in which only those bits are 1 where all the trains stop.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line of the *standard input*
> contains the count of trains (1≤*T*≤100)
> and the count of stations (1≤*S*≤100).
> The next *T* lines
> contain the sequences representing the routes of each train:
> *S* bits separated by spaces,
> where 1 means the train (row) stops at the given station (columnt),
> and 0 means the train does not stop.
>
> **Output**
>
> The first line of the *standard output* should contain
> a sequence of *S* bits separated by spaces,
> where 1 means all the trains stop,
> 0 means not all the trains stop.
>
> **Example**
>
> Input
>
> ```
> 6 8
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 
> 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 
> 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
> 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
> 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 
> 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1
> ```
>
> Output
>
> ```
> 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
> ```

this is my code in **C++**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    int trainStops[n][m];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            cin>>trainStops[i][j];
        }
    }
    int sum =0;
    int output[m]={0};
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            if(trainStops[j][i]==1){
                output[j]+=trainStops[j][i];
            }
        }
    }
cout<<"==============="<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        cout<<output[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dangerous stack-killer: `int trainStops[n][m];`. On a typical PC, if `m` and `n` are in the few hundreds, the programs automatic storage will be exhausted causing what's commonly known as a--wait for it!--Stack Overflow. This is but one of the reasons Variable Length Arrays are not legal in Standard C++.

Comment: Think on *where 1 means all the trains stop, 0 means not all the trains stop.* and how that relates to the numbers produced by `output[j]+=trainStops[j][i];`

Comment: 1-for me it doesn't matter the language you solve the task with since I will understand how it is working c and c++ for me is the same since you are not using the predefined functions in language libs but thank you so much for your answer and i agree with you

2-and for the "M" and "N" max and min it doesn't matter cuz I know how to do test cases to define maxM and maxN do it in a while loop or if a condition or catch an error  for second comment thank you so much and i m totally with you on that

Comment: for comment number 3
3- for me I tried to get sum of every column and as we know if the train stops in all stations means the column will have 1 in every station the sum will be the number of station which is the number of rows then using the for loop and if condition to check if output[i]==8 cout 1 not cout 0  i hope i clarify my answer thank you for asking

Comment: It's not all about you. The question must be useful to those that follow or it's not going to be preserved on the site and it's unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: The sum of the number of trains stopping is only part of the solution. the sum must be equal to the number of trains in order to be worth outputting.

Comment: The other problem with the code is easily picked off with a few minutes of debugging.

Comment: Also watch out for `int output[m] = { 0 };` This does NOT necessarily initialize all values of `output` to zero with a variable length array. Such are the wages of using a non-standard extension.

Comment: 90 words in one sentence is quite a feat, but not one to attract readers, especially when it's your opening sentence/paragraph. I'm having trouble identifying the question that's being asked.

Comment: thank you guys I m new in StackOverflow posting I did some mistakes in posting and i attached a picture of the task and my code and for how it must work i don't know that's why I asked and finally, I found a solution and share it with you guys and it is clear and if you have any question i will be more than happy to answer it

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solve it if there is another way I m interested to know thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    int trainStops[n][m];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            cin>>trainStops[i][j];
        }
    }
    int sum =0;
    int output[m]={0};
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
                output[i]+=trainStops[j][i];

        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        if(output[i]==n){
            cout<<1<<" ";
        }
        else{
            cout<<0<<" ";
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Answers should explain why the code answers the question. When an answer basically consists of just code, it tends to have little value to future visitors with the same question.

Comment: Looks almost identical to the solution I came up with. I took advantage of a little hack, though. When you print a `bool` with `<<` it spits out 1 or 0 unless you specifically ask for "true" or "false" with `boolalpha`. That means you can `for(int i=0; i<m; i++) cout << (output[i]==n)  << ' '; cout<<endl;`